# Is it correct to say "you wrote number 7 backwards / back to front / upside-down"?

Tags: phrase-usage

[image]

My daughter wrote number 7 like that

Is it correct to say "**you wrote number 7 backwards / back to front / upside-down / the wrong way round**"?

Comment: All except 'upside-down' are OK.

Comment: I think backwards is the most natural-sounding way to say it, thought I agree all except 'upside-down' are ok.

Comment: I would probably say "It is facing the wrong side."

Comment: @yunus - no native speaker would say that.